# Seekbar test not calling OnSeekBarChangeListener

Tags: android, android-espresso

I was working on a simple example for using a SeekBar, and am having problems getting my Espresso test to work.  When I run the tests, I can see the SeekBar move on the emulator screen, but it apparently is not calling the OnSeekBarChangeListener because the TextView doesn't change value ('Hello World!' is the initial value).  If I run the program and test it manually the TextView is updated as I expect.

Main Program:

```
package edu.eku.styere.seekbar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private int cur_progress = 0;
    boolean running = false;
    final int SEEK_MAX = 100;
    final int DELAY_MILLIS = 200;
    private TextView mProgressLabel;
    private SeekBar mProgressBar;

    // message handler
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // fetch items
        mProgressLabel = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.progress_text );
        mProgressBar = (SeekBar) findViewById( R.id.progress_seekbar );

        Button startButton = (Button) findViewById( R.id.btn_start );
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // start the timer/progresss bar
                cur_progress = 0;
                running = true;
                // start messages
                mHandler.postDelayed( mUpdateTimeTask, DELAY_MILLIS );
            }
        });

        // respond to changes in the seek bar by the user
        mProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener( new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            public void onProgressChanged( SeekBar sb, int progress, boolean fromUser ) {
                // user change or from us?
                if ( fromUser ) {
                    // user changed the bar, so get a new value
                    cur_progress = progress;

                    // update the text box
                    mProgressLabel.setText("progress: " + cur_progress );

                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
                    if ( running )
                        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, DELAY_MILLIS);
                }
            }

            // need to have these, but not using them here
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }

    // the runnable object that corresponds to our timer
    private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // done?
            if ( cur_progress >= SEEK_MAX ) {
                // stop everything
                mHandler.removeCallbacks( mUpdateTimeTask );
                running = false;
                return;
            }
            // update the progress
            cur_progress++;
            // update the text box
            mProgressLabel.setText("progress: " + cur_progress );
            // update the seek bar (does not cause onChange event)
            mProgressBar.setProgress( cur_progress );

            //do this again
            mHandler.postDelayed( this, DELAY_MILLIS );
        }
    }; // mUpdateTimeTask
}
```

Test Code:

```
package edu.eku.styere.seekbar;

import android.app.Instrumentation;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.support.test.espresso.UiController;
import android.support.test.espresso.ViewAction;
import android.support.test.espresso.action.CoordinatesProvider;
import android.support.test.espresso.action.GeneralSwipeAction;
import android.support.test.espresso.action.Press;
import android.support.test.espresso.action.Swipe;
import android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers;
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import android.test.InstrumentationTestCase;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import org.hamcrest.Matcher;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import java.util.Random;

import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivityTest {
    //Random rng = new Random();

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void moveSeekBar() {
        onView( withId( R.id.progress_seekbar )).perform(setProgress(35));

        // Check that the text was changed
        onView(withId(R.id.progress_text))
                .check(matches(withText("progress: " + 35)));
    }

    public static ViewAction setProgress(final int progress) {
        return new ViewAction() {
            @Override
            public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
                SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) view;
                seekBar.setProgress(progress);
            }
            @Override
            public String getDescription() {
                return "Set a progress on a SeekBar";
            }
            @Override
            public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
                return ViewMatchers.isAssignableFrom(SeekBar.class);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Result of the failed test:

```
android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'with text: is "progress: 35"' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: with text: is "progress: 35"
Got: "TextView{id=2131165185, res-name=progress_text, visibility=VISIBLE, width=480, height=29,
has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true,
is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false,
root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=72.0,
text=Hello world!, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}"

...
```

Comment: Add a slight 'delay' of 0.5sec to make sure the test isn't failing due to a race condition or something.

Comment: Hadn't thought of a race condition, but even a 5 second delay doesn't change anything :(

Answer (score 4):

Well after some more work I managed to create a solution to my problem, based on a GenericClickAction:

```
package edu.eku.styere.seekbar;

import android.support.test.espresso.ViewAction;
import android.support.test.espresso.action.CoordinatesProvider;
import android.support.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction;
import android.support.test.espresso.action.Press;
import android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap;
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import java.util.Random;

import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivityTest {
    Random rng = new Random();

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void moveSeekBar() {
        int cur_progress;

        // do an initial move in case the first random number is 0
        //  -- if it didn't move, the OnSeekBarChangeListener isn't called
        onView( withId( R.id.progress_seekbar )).perform(clickSeekBar(25));

        // try 10 random locations
        for( int i=0; i<10; i++ ) {
            cur_progress = rng.nextInt(101);            // 0..100

            // move it to a random location
            onView(withId(R.id.progress_seekbar)).perform(clickSeekBar(cur_progress));

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                // do nothing
            }
            // Check that the text was changed
            onView(withId(R.id.progress_text))
                    .check(matches(withText("progress: " + cur_progress)));
        }
    }

    public static ViewAction clickSeekBar(final int pos){
        return new GeneralClickAction(
                Tap.SINGLE,
                new CoordinatesProvider() {
                    @Override
                    public float[] calculateCoordinates(View view) {
                        SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) view;
                        final int[] screenPos = new int[2];
                        seekBar.getLocationOnScreen(screenPos);

                        // get the width of the actual bar area
                        // by removing padding
                        int trueWidth = seekBar.getWidth()
                                - seekBar.getPaddingLeft() - seekBar.getPaddingRight();

                        // what is the position on a 0-1 scale
                        //  add 0.3f to avoid roundoff to the next smaller position
                        float relativePos = (0.3f + pos)/(float) seekBar.getMax();
                        if ( relativePos > 1.0f )
                            relativePos = 1.0f;

                        // determine where to click
                        final float screenX = trueWidth*relativePos + screenPos[0]
                                + seekBar.getPaddingLeft();
                        final float screenY = seekBar.getHeight()/2f + screenPos[1];
                        float[] coordinates = {screenX, screenY};

                        return coordinates;
                    }
                },
                Press.FINGER);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an assertion failure where it seems as if the output is identical ("progress: 35").  However, it may fail an assertion with <4> is not equal to <4> when one is a string and one is an int.  That could be a possibility with the way progress is getting placed/evaluated.

Edit: (sorry too low reputation to comment).  Is it the "fromUser" boolean?  I'm using some very similar code that is working, but I do not check that boolean...

Comment: No, if you look closely at the "Got..." you eventually get to where you find that the TextView still contains "Hello World!".  Besides, in the 5 second delay test I could see on the screen that the TextView didn't change.